# "conda export" can not export packages that is installed through pip

Tags: pip, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I want to use package `untangle`, unfortunately, it can not be installed through conda, I have to install it using pip. And when I use `conda export` to export the requirement file, I find that the requirement file doesn't include `untangle`, is there any way to also include it in conda requirement file and export the conda virtual enviroment ? Thanks

Comment: I can help But few things I want to ask, Are your pip and anaconda in the same environment? Have pip installed packages worked for you on notebook before? and what are you using Mac or Windows ?@zjffdu

Comment: Thanks @DeepakM, I am using Mac, and pip and anaconda are in the same enviroment, pip installed packages works for me.

Comment: Can you use the untangle package with python (without conda) in that environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/Users/Deepak/anaconda/bin/pip install untangle
```

Just change "Deepak" to whatever your user folder name is. The anaconda bin folder is the recommended folder in which you should actually store your pip installations within the Anaconda environment.
Open or restart your Jupyter kernel. Try a simple import like this:

```
import untangle
print("Imported Untangle successfully!")
```

It worked for me, should work for you too.

Comment: Run pip works for me. But I am afraid it would install untangle globally instead of the current conda enviroment. What I want is to install it in the current enviroment and be able to export it using conda for another conda enviroment.